# Openstreetcam extract image and gps location

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, openstreetmap

I would like to use python to download the image and sequences of images found in the location on openstreetcam.

http://openstreetcam.com/details/8552/422

I figured out the image is saved under

http://api.openstreetcam.org/files/photo/2016/6/30/lth/8552_2fbf0_57756eba868e9.jpg?v=1518090956232

however there is no official API to use. How would one extract the image and gps data?

Edit: The GPS data can be found in the url by clicking Edit OSM id.

Ideally one would use some sort of web scraper however the .jpg is not found  in the website source code.

Answer (score 1):

OSC's endpoints are a little hidden.

Invite you to check out https://github.com/Streets-Data-Collaborative/osc-tools where I've written some scripts to extract track data and the underlying metadata for each track.

Feel free to open an issue on the repo if something's not working.